# Find all possibles values. Looks Hard. Is it hard?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, root-systems

I need some help, (or advise) how I can solve this problem and in which category I need to put it. 
The problem state: Let m be a solution of the equation $ y^{2015}-15 y+ 14=0$. Find all possible values for $1+m+m^2+ …+m^{(2015-1)}$.

I can easy see that $m=1 $ is solution of such equation, and m is also a solution by definition. I’m thinking in the superposition principle due to be a sum of all the possible solution is also a solution. But I am not sure how it is possible find all possible values.

Thanks .

Answer (score 9):

Notice that $m\neq 0$ and rewrite the condition as $m^{2015}=15m-14$. You already thought about the case $m=1$.

If $m\neq 1$
$$1+m+\dots + m^{2014}=\frac{m^{2015}-1}{m-1}=\frac{15m-15}{m-1}=15.$$

Comment: Extra tough : 1) The problem ask me about all possible values… this is only for such a sum 1+m+…+m^2014 the sum??? I’m saying is only 15 the unique value? I’m think what is the value of m to be the sum 15?? I’m interpreted wrongly the statement? I hope, I express my concerns well. Thanks!

Comment: If $m=1$ we obviously get $2015$. Now if $m\neq 1$ and $m$ solves the equation $m^{2015}=15m-14$, what I showed is that the sum is always $15$. In other words, for any solution of the equation different from $1$ the result is always $15$.

Comment: Only to make sure that I understand well, the entire sum can have only two values 2015 or 15, no more. (Which will be the final answer,no?). But, is there any way to calculate the values of all the roots (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra) of such polynomial? Thanks, again.

Comment: To find all the roots of that polynomial seems impossible to me.